# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException does not recognize left square bracket "["

Tags: c#, json, exception, json.net

I'm trying to use `DeserializeObject` from the NewtonSoft library but I encoutered a problem that bothers me a lot.

I'm quite new with that Library so to understand it better I took a look at the following [example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) from the official website.

Using that ressource, I modified it to fit my needs, here is my class :

```
public class Project
{
    [JsonProperty ("team")]
    public string Team{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("details")]
    public string Details { get;  set;}
}
```

Here is the code :

```
Project project = new Project();
string json_string = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.json", Encoding.UTF8);
project = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Projets>(json_string);
```

And here is the .json file template :

```
{
   "Team": "nameOfTeam",
   "Details": [
       {
       "detail1": "Unknown",
       "detail2": "Unknown"
       }
   ]
}
```

Problem is, there is an exception during the run-time with the following message

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'Details', line X, position XX.

I don't understand how the character "[" could be a problem here, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Details` is a string in your C# class, while it's an array in the JSON object. Either make it a string in JSON, or make the property an `IList<string>` instead.

Comment: Ah I see. Thing is I saw an another exemple where the configuration was quite similar and the person behind the code did not have any problem with using a string in his class while it was an array in the Json. Thank you.